# Mirror a site using php

Tags: php, mirroring, mirror

I have to  mirror a site using php.
I am using the google code of the following link
 http://code.google.com/p/php-dynamic-mirror/

I have specified all the settings as it was given in docs.
But when I go to the mirror site url its always give me a 404 page not found error.
Any help will be highly appreciated here is the link of my mirror site
http://tinyurl.com/99p99og

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/).

> HTTrack is a free (GPL, libre/free software) and easy-to-use offline browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.
>
> WinHTTrack is the Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Seven release of HTTrack, and WebHTTrack the Linux/Unix/BSD release.

Comment: thanx praveen but i need to replicate my site on other server have you looked on the link i have specified?

Comment: I saw that it says 404! But why don't you mirror it locally and then upload via FTP? This software even parses flash! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `wget`. If you don't have a [cygwin](http://cygwin.org) or a unix box to run `wget` on there are [win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) packages about.

```
wget --mirror http://www.example.org/
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/155743/how-to-refresh-an-online-website-mirror-created-with-wget-mirror

Answer (score 0):

We use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for that:

> rsync is a software application and network protocol for Unix-like
>   systems with ports to Windows that synchronizes files and directories
>   from one location to another while minimizing data transfer by using
>   delta encoding when appropriate. Quoting the official website: "rsync
>   is a file transfer program for Unix systems. rsync uses the 'rsync
>   algorithm' which provides a very fast method for bringing remote files
>   into sync."[3] An important feature of rsync not found in most similar
>   programs/protocols is that the mirroring takes place with only one
>   transmission in each direction. rsync can copy or display directory
>   contents and copy files, optionally using compression and recursion.